# websocket protocol 08 write error Unrecognized frame opcode: 12

Tags: c++, websocket

I am using the new websocket protocol: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17 to write a server in c++.
I can receive and decode data correctly from the client (chrome browser)

When I want to send data from my server to the browser I receive this error: 
 **Unrecognized frame opcode: 12**

My first byte is 0x81 as I am sending Text. The browser receive the message correctly however, after I get this error the websocket connection get killed.

Do you know what can go wrong?

Comment: You really need to provide more information to make the question answerable. Can you post a link to source? What browser? Where are you getting the "unrecognized frame opcode: 12"? From the browser onerror handler? As an unhandled exception? How are you verifying that the first byte is 0x81? How do you know the browser receives the message correctly? Is the browser sending a close frame after?

Comment: Have you made any progress?  I have a working protocol 0 server app working for Safari and Mobile Safari.  For protocol 6, I can establish an open connection between my server app and both firefox and chrome, but can not send or receive messages.